# Regex - question about finding every word in a string that begins with a letter

Tags: python, regex, python-re

```
import re

random_regex = re.compile(r'^\w')
x = random_regex.findall('RoboCop eats baby food. BABY FOOD.')
print(x)
```

This is the code I have, following along on *Automate the Boring Stuff with Python*. However I kind of side-tracked a bit and wanted to see if I could get a list of all the words in the string passed in `random_regex.findall()` that begin with a word, so I wrote `\w` for the regex pattern. However for some reason my output only prints "R" and not the rest of the letters in the string, Would anyone be able to explain why/tell me how to fix this problem?

Comment: `\w` = one letter.  `\w+` = all the letters.

Comment: For future reference I suggest you read the [Regular Expression HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html) in the online documentation — specifically the [Matching Characters](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#matching-characters) section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re
random_regex = re.compile(r'\w+')
x = random_regex.findall('RoboCop eats baby food. BABY FOOD.')
print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

^ Requires the start of a string, so it only finds RoboCop.  Use \w+ to get all of the letters.  You can test your regex at regex101.com.

```
random_regex = re.compile(r'\w+')

x = random_regex.findall('RoboCop eats baby food. BABY FOOD.')
```

to get x:
['RoboCop', 'eats', 'baby', 'food', 'BABY', 'FOOD']

Comment: just `r'\b\w+'` would do

Answer (score 0):

A regex find all should work here:

```py
inp = "RoboCop eats baby food. BABY FOOD."
words = re.findall(r'\w+', inp)
print(words)  # ['RoboCop', 'eats', 'baby', 'food', 'BABY', 'FOOD']
```